# How to process the output folder created by one script

Tags: bash, sh

I have a script (first.sh) which creates a output folder at a particular location.Now a second script (second.sh) need the location of this output folder as it need to process the data into it.

Keep in mind that the first.sh script will generate the output folder as per the user needs.(as per path set by the user).

Now i need the second.sh script to find the path of the output folder generated by first.sh script and then it should enter into it for processing some data?

I need the logic for the above problem. Also remember that the path for output folder always changes and the second.sh script should be able to find the exact path and output folder.

first.sh /add/sub/output_folder (user decides the output path)

second.sh
It should find the "/add/sub/output_folder" location

Hope it helps.Plz help me.

Comment: Do `first.sh` and `second.sh` always run one after another?

Answer (score 0):

More details of what the both scripts do would be helpfull.

I assume you can not/ don't lunch second.sh form first.sh because this would be the easiest option.

One way of approaching this would be to output the folder location to a property file by first.sh that second.sh has access to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to call `second.sh` from `first.sh` you can do

```
first.sh $YOUR_OUTPUT_PATH
```

You can get access to that path by using `$1`, e.g.

```
echo $1
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the manner in which you are calling your code, you can probably use $PPID to generate a primitive means by which script 1 and script 2 can exchange information.

`$PPID` is the parent-process-id of your script. In the following example, both scripta.sh and scriptb.sh see the same value:

scripta.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
datadir=/tmp/$PPID.tmp
mkdir -p $datadir
sleep $(( RANDOM % 60 ))
echo Some data from $PPID/$$ on $(tty) >$datadir/testfile.txt_tmp
mv $datadir/testfile.txt_tmp $datadir/testfile.txt
```

scriptb.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
datadir=/tmp/$PPID.tmp
timeout=60
while (( (i=i+1) < timeout )); do
  cat $datadir/testfile.txt 2>&- && break
  sleep 1
done
```

This example will hold for up to 60 seconds for the data to appear and will work no matter how many users are active.
You should test this by running the following on two or more separate terminals.

```
scripta.sh &
scriptb.sh &
```

You'll need another script (or overnight process) to clean up the datadir directories.

BTW, I do not recommend /tmp as a holding zone for these files. Create a buffer directory somewhere else where there is lots of space.